# Checkers on a Chessboard

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

Given 2k pieces on a k by k chessboard, prove that there is always a sequence of pieces $K_1, K_2 \ldots K_{2n}$ such that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are in the same row, $K_2$ and $K_3$ are in the same column, $K_3$ and $K_4$ are in the same row ... $K_{2n-1}$ and $K_{2n}$ are in the same row, and $K_{2n}$ and $K_1$ are in the same column. This sequence does not necessarily contain all the pieces on the board.

Comment: Can you clarify if $k$ and $n$ are intended to be the same, or are they allowed to be different?

Comment: They can be different. The sequence can be shorter than length of 2k.

Comment: @BrianTam:  Without a relationship, it is trivial.  Take n = 1.  Because 2k > k, by the pigeonhole principle you have that there is at least 1 row with > 1 piece.  $K_1$ is in the same column as $K_1$, so all requirements are met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do this is motivated by graph theory.

Let $R=\{r_1,r_2,\dots, r_k\}$ and $C=\{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k\}$, and consider $R\cup C$ as a set of vertices. For each position $(i,j)$ on the chessboard with a checker, draw an edge between the vertices $r_i$ and $c_j$. This will create a graph with $2k$ vertices and $2k$ edges. A graph with at least as many edges as vertices must contain a cycle. Follow the cycle (which must alternate between vertices in $R$ and vertices in $C$ by construction, so must have even length) to get your sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the length of the sequence is unimportant. What matters is that we can always continue the sequence in a nontrivial way. Any such sequence can be continued forever giving a "circuit" on the chessboard.

We will prove this by induction. Our base case is the $2\times 2$ chess board, where the solution is obvious because every square has a piece on it. Now we consider an $n\times n$ chess board.

**Case 1:** Every row and column has exactly 2 pieces in it. We can start anywhere on the board, and we're guaranteed to be able to find our sequence.

**Case 2:** There exists a row (or column) with fewer than 2 pieces. We'll assume without loss of generality that there is a row, $r$, with fewer than 2 pieces. **Subcase i:** (There are no pieces in row $r$) The average number of pieces is a column is 2 because there are $2n$ pieces and $n$ columns. Find a column with 2 pieces. Delete row $r$ and the column with 2 pieces, obtaining an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ checkerboard with $2(n-1)$ pieces. **Subcase ii:** (There is one piece in row $r$) If the column containing the piece in row $r$ has only 2 pieces, then row $r$ and column containing the piece in row $r$. Otherwise that column has $3$ pieces, so there is a column with only one piece. Delete row $r$ and the column with one piece. We then obtain an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ checkerboard with $2(n-1)$ pieces. By induction, the proof is complete.

Edited to note that when I say "delete a row and column", I mean ignore them and find a sequence on the resulting $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ chessboard.

Comment: I just edited my post to clarify this. The length of the sequence is completely irrelevant. If every row and column has 2 entries, we can continue our sequence forever.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I missed that part and my solution is incorrect.

Comment: Case 1 doesn't depend on induction.  It is more like a Eulerean path on a graph.  You arrive at a checker in one direction and are guaranteed another checker in the direction you want, so you never get stuck.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think case 1 is fine. Consider the pieces as vertices of a graph and connect two vertices if and only if they belong in the same row or column. The resulting graph, by hypothesis of there being precisely two pieces in each column and row, has only vertices of degree two. This means that it is a union of cycles and it's straightforward to check that traversing any cycle gives a sequence of the required type.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm not sure what you mean. It doesn't seem like the problem requires the loop to be of a given length (perhaps I'm misunderstanding you somewhere).

Comment: Hm, that is likely my bad then. I interpreted that $k$ and $n$ were the same value. If in fact they need not be, then my objections are invalid.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think it's most likely the case that $k$ and $n$ need to be seperate. Consider this layout for a $3\times 3$ board $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ The only sequence possible is the $2\times 2$ loop in the upper-left corner. It's not possible to construct one of length $6$.

Comment: Yea, my interpretation is wrong. Sorry about the confusion.